# (standard_in) illegal character when looping through a for loop

Tags: bash, proc

I'm trying to get statistics related to processes and general system information. If I do it without looping it runs fine, but if I put it within a loop it just gives me a chained error of illegal characters.

```
#!/bin/bash
TOTALMEM=$(awk '{ print $1 }' /proc/meminfo)
l=$(ls /proc | grep '[0-9]$')

for pid in $l
do
    PID=$pid
    cmd=$(cat /proc/$PID/cmdline)
    state=$(awk '{ print $3 }' /proc/$PID/stat)
    utime=$(awk '{ print $14 }' /proc/$PID/stat)
    stime=$(awk '{ print $15 }' /proc/$PID/stat)
    pr=$(awk '{ print $18 }' /proc/$PID/stat)
    state=$(awk '{ print $3 }' /proc/$PID/stat) 
    ttime=$(($utime+$stime))
    mem=$(cat /proc/$PID/status | grep VmSize: | awk '{ print $2 }')
    memp=$(echo "scale=2;$TOTALMEM / $mem" | bc -l)
    memp="$memp%"
    mem=$(echo "scale=2;$mem / 1024" | bc -l)
    cpu=$ttime
    usr=$(stat -c '%U' /proc/$PID)

    process_string="$PID $usr $pr $mem $state $cpu $memp $ttime $cmd"
    echo $process_string
done
```

This is a sample of the prompted errors. It's all like it (random characters giving the error), repeated a bunch of times for every index (from 1 to 44).

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
```

Once it ends at the 44th index, it prints the variable $process_string without the $memp (memory percentage usage) value. This seems to happen with every $pid (process).

If I put it into a for loop then it breaks, but if I don't, it doesn't break and I don't know why it is working this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it has a few bug-fixes and speed improvements, including:

- not parsing ls
- using `awk | read` instead of calling `awk` multiple times for different fields of the same $pid/stat file
- not using `cat | grep | awk` where just `awk` will do
- skip entries without a VMSize.

Note the comment about VmSize - it skips all procs that don't have a VmSize entry.  You may want to use some other method to determine "$mem" in those cases instead of just skipping.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TOTALMEM=$(awk '/^MemTotal:/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo)

for pid in /proc/[0-9]* ; do
    PID=$(basename $pid)
    cmd=$(cat $pid/cmdline)

    # use `awk | read` to avoid multiple calls to awk
    awk '{print $3,$14,$15,$18}' $pid/stat | read state utime stime pr


    ttime=$((utime + stime))

    # not all procs have a VmSize entry in status
    mem=$(awk '/VmSize:/ { print $2 }' $pid/status)

    # empty "$mem" causes a syntax error in bc
    if [ -n "$mem" ] ; then
      memp=$(echo "scale=2;$TOTALMEM / $mem" | bc -l)
      memp="$memp%"

      mem=$(echo "scale=2;$mem / 1024" | bc -l)
      cpu=$ttime
      usr=$(stat -c '%U' $pid)

      process_string="$PID $usr $pr $mem $state $cpu $memp $ttime $cmd"
      echo $process_string
    fi

done
```

Comment: anonymous downvoter: if you're going to downvote, at least have the courtesy to explain why?  what's so wrong with this answer that it deserves a downvote?

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working. Although compressing the awk into a single statement and piping it to read gave me an error (permission denied, IIRC). Right now I don't care about optimization, but I'll keep it in mind when I redo it (it's for college but I'd like to make it more usable than just for an assignment).

I still wonder why that popped up when looping but not when doing it over just a single process. I thought it could be about the directory not existing but it didn't seem logical to me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably intended something more like this for the first assignment:

```
TOTALMEM=$(awk '{ print $2 }' /proc/meminfo | head -n 1)
```

since otherwise you will get a lot of values (unquoted) in this line:

```
memp=$(echo "scale=2;$TOTALMEM / $mem" | bc -l)
```

A better use of awk would be to match the actual label you are looking for, e.g.,

```
TOTALMEM=$(awk '/^MemTotal:/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo | head -n 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why that didn't pop up without the for loop. That could explain why I wasn't reading correctly the memory usage.

The error still persists though. The index now it's only 1 2 1 2 all over again. It doesn't seem to be about bad parsed input again (although I guess it is), but I'll work on it tomorrow since now I'm kinda burned out with it; bash is way more annoying than anything I've worked with before.

Comment: It didn't fix my whole problem although you pointing that out helped a lot. If I could vote you, I'd do it.

I'm still clueless as why that passed through a single iteration and did not when looping over a bunch of PIDs, or why the overall change of behaviour.

Anyway, thank you so much for your time.